# Programmatically rename a table and all its references in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

How to rename a table and all its references in SQL Server ? Programmatically will be preferred , but any tools also will do equally good.

References include stored procedures, view and other database objects as well.

Objects which depend on the table as well as objects on which the table depends.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change any reference to _the table_ inside stored procedures? If so, this will never be a guarantee, since a table name can be built/referenced dynamically.

Comment: You would be better off looking at the system tables. For example for  stored procs look in `syscomments`, (there is 4 or 5 other tables to consider) do a select, drop the stored proc, change the table name and use it to recreate. It is all possible by script but there is a lot to remember!

Comment: @Mackan: Do you mean you want to change any reference to the table inside stored procedures? - Yes!

Comment: @Fred: I am looking for a generic script which can take an Object name(in this case a table name) and then rename tables inside all dependent objects automatically.

Comment: TRY APEXSQL Search http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_search.aspx

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't trust a script/program to do this. I would build a query to look for any references, display the affected tables/views/SPs, and then change them manually. But if you **know** that there are no complex SP's, maybe it's worth a shot at scripting it.

Comment: @VinayPratapSingh: Looks good. but exact tool name ?

Comment: http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_refactor.aspx its free but try it on a backup db first!!

Comment: Fred: Thanks. I will try it.Of Course on backup DB first.

Comment: @Fred great advice, it will be better to test any tool on a backup db first.

Comment: Why would this be worth the trouble?  This is going to be a whole lot of trouble for very little gain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do using SQL Server Data Tools and Visual Studio refactoring feature.(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa833262(v=vs.80).aspx)

Or by using SQL Server Data Tools
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272704(v=vs.103).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Too rename a table use the `ALTER` function

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
RENAME TO new_table_name;
```

To rename a view use the System Stored Procedure `sp_rename`

```
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.view_name', 'new_view_name'
```

The same goes for renaming Stored Procedures

```
EXEC sp_rename 'sp_stored_procedure_name', 'sp_new_stored_procedure_name'
```

Comment: Thanks Matt.That will rename just one table. But i also need to rename all dependent objects like stored procedures, views etc.

Comment: Then this is not what you want to do.

Comment: 1019 stored procedures, 52 views, some triggers and functions etc.

Comment: @Fred : Agree! So I am looking for some tool or query powerfull enough to do that.

Comment: There is no built-in procedure that does this. This is why when executing sp_rename you get a warning that dependant objects may be invalid.  You can write something with dynamic coding, but it heavily depends on your coding standarts.